# I need to pass the session server name trhow FSessionSettings - Unreal Engine 5

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, unreal-engine5, unrealscript

I'm new in Unreal Engine 5 Multiplayer.
I need to pass the session server name trhow FSessionSettings for show the session name in a Session List in the search games menu.

I wrote the code but I get an error when trying to compile.

This is my current code:

```
void UMultiplayerSessionSubsystem::ConfigureSessionSettings(UMultiplayerDataAsset* DataAsset)
{
    FName SubsystemName = IOnlineSubsystem::Get()->GetSubsystemName();
    const FName NullName = "NULL";

    SessionSettings = MakeShareable(new FOnlineSessionSettings());
    SessionSettings->NumPublicConnections = DataAsset->MaxPlayersCount;
    SessionSettings->NumPrivateConnections = DataAsset->MaxPlayersCount;
    SessionSettings->bIsLANMatch = SubsystemName == NullName;
    SessionSettings->bIsDedicated = false;
    SessionSettings->bAllowJoinInProgress = true;
    SessionSettings->bAllowJoinViaPresence = true;
    SessionSettings->bUseLobbiesIfAvailable = true;
    SessionSettings->bShouldAdvertise = true;
    SessionSettings->bUsesPresence = true;
    SessionSettings->bAllowInvites = true;

    FOnlineSessionSetting CompoundSessionName;
    CompoundSessionName.Data = DataAsset->OwnerPlayerName;
    SessionSettings->Settings.Add(FName("SESSION_NAME"), CompoundSessionName);

    SessionSettings->Set(FName("MatchType"), DataAsset->GameTypeName.ToString(), EOnlineDataAdvertisementType::ViaOnlineServiceAndPing);
}
```

I need to see the server name:

```
FString SessionName = LastSessionSearch->SearchResults[i].Session.SessionSettings.Settings.FindRef("SESSION_NAME").Data.ToString();

UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("SERVER NAME: %s"), *SessionName);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *I wrote the code but I get an error when trying to compile*. What is the error? Post the full error message.